# How to remove the Junit4 from eclipse test runner

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I wrote the test case for junit3.

In eclipse test runner there are Junit 3 and Junit4.

If I use junit 4 I can not run each individual testmethod. So I want to use only Junit 3.

I removed the junit4 plugin from eclipse/plugin. Still I am seeing the Junit4 tag  in the test runner option.

How can I remove Junit4 from my test runner option?

Comment: If you want to use JUnit3 in Eclipse, it is perfectly possible by choosing JUnit3 in the Junit Test launch configuration. What you are asking for is complete removal of JUnit from Eclipse, and IMHO that's absurd. Just use an older version of Eclipse with no support for JUnit4.

Answer (score 3):

You **can** run an individual testmethod with Junit 4. Just right-click on the method in the outline and choose "run with Junit".

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but it doesn't work for those of us using JUnit 3.  All methods get run anyway, and everything other than the selected method show up under "Unrooted tests".